# Create command to compare 2 items

Tags: minipage

I want to compare JSON and XML in a tabular minipage (not sure if this is right)

I was able to make this

[image]

whit this

```
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
 \ac{JSON} & \ac{XML} \\
\hline
 1 & 2 \\
\hline 
 4 & 5 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

I know how I would have to write this, if I would want to make it without an new command, that extracts this part of my code.

But I want an command that extracts this code from my writing tex file to keep it clean and readable (for LaTex beginners like me).
So I came up with the idea to make a command for one line in the block so i created this two commands.

```
\newcommand{\compareline}|[2]
{
     #1 & #2 \\
    \hline 
}
\newcommand{\endingcompareline}[2]
{
     #1 & #2
}
```

But when I want to translate my document, I get these errors.

```
./commands.tex:37: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.37     #
        1 & #2 \\
./commands.tex:37: Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.37     #1 &
            #2 \\
./commands.tex:37: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.37     #1 & #
             2 \\
./commands.tex:38: Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.38    \hline
```

I would want to use these commands in a way like this

```
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
 \compareline{JSON}{XML}
 \compareline{1}{2}
 \endingcompareline{4}{5}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

I don't know it better but is my approach to this wrong or do I miss one slight detail in my command code?

Comment: If you want help with an error it is always best to post the code that produces the error, but `\newcommand{\compareline}|[2]` has a spurious `|` perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: @David Carlisle You are right, this solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 \newcommand{\compareline}|[2]
```

has a spurious `|`